# OAuth2 Architecture with 2 Resource Servers having their own Different Scopes

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, openid-connect

Is it possible to have an OAuth2 setup involving a central Auth Server and multiple Resource servers **having their own access scopes**. For example `clientApp` accesses `resource-server-A` with `scope1,scope2` and access `resource-server-B` having access scope `scope3 scope4`.

While this might be possible, how do we show all the above access scopes during authorization time of the `clientApp`? Is there a standard, OAuth/open-id way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely possible. [RFC8707 - Resource Indicators for OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8707) standardized the common practice, that many Authorization Server implementations adopted over the years, to allow OAuth 2.0 Clients to indicate which resource servers they intend to use an Access Token at.

With RFC8707 in place your Client Application can start an authorization request like

```
/authorization_endpoint?...&scope=scope1%20scope2%20scope3%20scope4%20&resource=urn:resource-server:A&resource=urn:resource-server:B
```

Given that both resource servers are registered at the AS it's the AS's job to recognize scope1 and scope2 beloging to resource A, etc. Note that if a scope value is recognized for both resources the result is a cartesian product of all the scopes at all the target services.

It is a best practice to only have Access Tokens for a single resource server and to accomodate that the resource parameter then becomes a parameter for the Access Token Request as well. Combine that with Refresh Tokens and you get a Refresh Token valid to issue Access Tokens for a different resource at a time as you call the Refresh Token grant.

Comment: Thanks Filip, this was exactly what i was looking for. One followup perhaps i can ask, in our current approach, there is no way for the `auth-sever` to store the __scopes__ for `resource-server-B`, but __is__ aware of the resource-server-B itself. Is there a way for the Auth-server to call the resource-server-B's endpoint to get its scopes? Maybe i'm making it complicated.

Comment: There's no standard around AS<>RS negotiation or discovery at the moment.

Comment: not sure if i got it right. the access token endpoint will expect a resource parameter so that it can issue an access token for a single resource. But what about the auth code returned to the client? if the client specifies two resources in the request would AS return a single auth code to be used across both access token grants?

Comment: The implementations on this may differ, some ASs will require the access token request to be accompanied by a resource parameter, some will choose one of the many to be used by default. The request result in a refresh token being issued which can be used right away to get an access token for the "other" resource.